# Cannot select first child in css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here is my code

```css
div p:first-child{
    border-left: 5px solid #bdc3c7;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>1 January 2018</h3>
  <h1>This is my first Article</h1>
  <p>First</p>
  <p>Second</p>
  <p>Third</p>
</div>
```

I want the first paragraph to have a left border. According to this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) page, this can be done using `first-child` but mine doesn't work for some reason.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `:first-child` selector only selects the first child of its parent regardless of type. Your `<p>` is the third child of its `<div>` parent. To select the first child of a given type, use the `:first-of-type` instead:

```css
div p:first-of-type {
  border-left: 5px solid #bdc3c7;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>1 January 2018</h3>
  <h1>This is my first Article</h1>
  <p>First</p>
  <p>Second</p>
  <p>Third</p>
</div>
```

**EDIT** To clarify how `:first-child` works, when you say `div p:first-child`, you're not selecting the first `p` child of any `div`. You're still selecting the first child of any `div`, but only if that child happened to be `p`. So it is kind of additional restriction.

In the example below, I used a cyan background for `:first-child`. You can see that it got applied to the two titles even though they have different types. Then I used a red border for `p:first-child`. You can see that this time it only got applied to the second title because it is `p`, and it didn't apply to the first title because it is not `p` (i.e. it is `h3`):

```css
div :first-child {
  background-color: #0ff;
}

div p:first-child {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>This is my first Article</h3>
  <p>First</p>
  <p>Second</p>
  <p>Third</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>This is my second Article</p>
  <p>First</p>
  <p>Second</p>
  <p>Third</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah. I see. So the `p` in `p:first-child` here is kind of redundant isn't it?

Comment: Not exactly. `p:first-child` _only_ applies formatting if the first child of the `div` happens to be a `p` element. This can be useful in many situations (just not yours!)

Comment: No, it's not redundant, but it is not doing what you think it does. If you don't use it, then the style will apply to every first child of every `div`. When you use it, it will apply to every child of every `div` ONLY if that first child happen to be `p`. See my edit answer for a full explanation and example.

Comment: I see. I guess I should've researched more before using it. Thanks for explaining in such a coherent manner

Answer (score 3):

`:first-child` only selects elements that are the first child of their parents. Your `<p>` is the third child of your `<div>`, so it doesn't work.

Try using `:first-of-type` instead:

```
div p:first-of-type {
    border-left: 5px solid #bdc3c7;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but the `<p>` isn't the first child of the `<div>` -- the `<h3>` is, so the 
`<p>` won't be selected by `first-child`.

Try it using [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child):

```css
div p:nth-child(3) {
  border-left: 5px solid #bdc3c7;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>1 January 2018</h3>
  <h1>This is my first Article</h1>
  <p>First</p>
  <p>Second</p>
  <p>Third</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The paragraph is not the first child.

Try with:

```
div p:first-of-type {
    border-left: 5px solid #bdc3c7;
}
```

Or, what is the same:

```
div p:nth-of-type(1) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `div p:nth-child(3)` or you can use `div p:first-of-type` either way it will work.

The `:first-of-type` CSS pseudo-class represents the first element of its type among a group of sibling elements.

The `:nth-child()` CSS pseudo-class matches one or more elements based on their position among a group of siblings.

Documentation for `:nth-child()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

Documentation for `:first-of-type` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type).

For using `:first-of-type` use:

```
div p:first-of-type {
  border-left: 5px solid #bdc3c7;
}
```

Or for using `:nth-child(3)` use:

```
div p:nth-child(3) {
  boder-left: 5px solid #bdc3c7;
}
```